# Parsing QIF file - .NET ported to Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have code that parses a .qif file using .NET.  I'm attempting to port this code to Java, but am having trouble with the Regular Expression that does part of the parsing.  Here is a sample of the beginning of the file:

```
!Type:Tag
NAdam
DSon
^
NAllison
^
NAmber
DSabrina's Sister
^
NAnthony
^
```

In .NET, I can use this code to start the parsing:

```
// Read the entire file
string input = reader.ReadToEnd();

// Split the file by header types
string[] transactionTypes = Regex.Split(input, @"^(!.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

When I debug the .NET parser, I see the following:

```
transactionTypes[0] = ""
transactionTypes[1] = "!Type:Tag\r"
transactionTypes[2] = "\nNAdam\r\nDSon\r\n^\r\nNAllison\r\n^NAmber\r\nDSabrina's Sister\r\nNAnthony\r\n^
```

In Java, it seems to always skip the `!Type:Tag` line, so I don't know the type being parsed.  I tried various versions of the Regular Expression in Java, including the following:

```
String[] transactionTypes = dataToParse.split("!.*");
String[] transactionTypes = dataToParse.split("\\s*^(!.*)\\s*");
String[] transactionTypes = dataToParse.split("\\s*(?m)^(!.*)$\\s*");
```

When I say it skips the `!Type:Tag` line, I see the following while debugging:

```
transactionTypes[0] = ""
transactionTypes[1] = "\nNAdam\r\nDSon\r\n^\r\nNAllison\r\n^NAmber\r\nDSabrina's Sister\r\nNAnthony\r\n^
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: split removes the matched splitter, so that is why your match is disappearing.

Comment: (?<=^.*\r)\n will produce a two element array based on your input it will consume the first \n though.

Comment: looks like split will always consume something so if you want a splitter that does not you may have to roll your own.

Comment: @BevynQ that explains it!  if you write it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure regex is necessary for this? From what I gleaned about the .qif format, it looks more like it was made for reading line by line. Read a line, if it starts with "!" it's a header line, then the following lines are an object, with a line that consists of "^" being a separator between objects, etc. Lots of line-by-line file reading examples in this SO thread:

[How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-in-java)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicken_Interchange_Format